# sweetalert confirmation on delete in angularjs on http request not working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-controller, sweetalert

I am new to angularjs, i am having a problem where i am using sweetalert for alert messages. My problem here is i am getting the sweetalert confirmation box on delete button click, but "yes" and "no" events are not working inside it. I found only answers based on ajax request but i did not find on httprequest within the angularjs scope. Help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
 var app = angular.module("myapp", ['sweetalert'])
 app.controller("ProductController", function ($scope, $http) {   
   $scope.delete = function (qid) {
        swal({
            title: "Are you sure?",
            text: "Your will not be able to recover this imaginary file!",
            type: "warning",
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete it!",
            cancelButtonText: "No, cancel plx!",
            closeOnConfirm: false,
            closeOnCancel: false,
            showLoaderOnConfirm: true
        },
     function(isConfirm){ 
         if (!isConfirm) {
             swal("Cancelled", "Your imaginary file is safe :)", "error");
         }else{
             $http(httpreq).then(function (data) {
                 var httpreq = {
                     method: 'POST',
                     url: 'Product.aspx/delete',
                     headers: {
                         'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                         'dataType': 'json'
                     },
                     data: { qid: qid }
                 }
                 swal("Deleted!", "Your imaginary file has been deleted.", "success");                          
             });  
            }
         });
     };   });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have wrong functional part of swal.

[Here's a fixed sample code.](https://jsfiddle.net/Canet/42ceox43/4/)

Change your code like this.

**Original Code**

```
swal({
    title: "Are you sure?",
    text: "Your will not be able to recover this imaginary file!",
    type: "warning",
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete it!",
    cancelButtonText: "No, cancel plx!",
    closeOnConfirm: false,
    closeOnCancel: false
},function(isConfirm){ 
    if (!isConfirm) return;
    $http(httpreq).then(function (data) {
        var httpreq = {
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'Product.aspx/delete',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                'dataType': 'json'
            },
            data: { qid: qid }
        }
        swal("Deleted!", 
             "Your imaginary file has been deleted.", 
             "success");
        }).catch(function (error) {
             swal("Cancelled", 
                  "Your imaginary file is safe :)", 
                  "error");                 
        });
    });
});
```

**Modified Code**

```
swal({
    title: "Are you sure?",
    text: "Your will not be able to recover this imaginary file!",
    type: "warning",
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete it!",
    cancelButtonText: "No, cancel plx!",
    closeOnConfirm: false,
    closeOnCancel: false,
    showLoaderOnConfirm: true           // Add this line
}, function(isConfirm){
    if (!isConfirm) {
        swal("Cancelled", "Your imaginary file is safe :)", "error");
    } else {
        // $timeout is sample code. Put your http call function into here instead of $timeout.
        $timeout(function(){
            swal("Deleted!", "Your imaginary file has been deleted.", "success");
        },2000);

        /*$http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'Product.aspx/delete',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                'dataType': 'json'
            },
            data: { qid: qid }
        }).then(function (data) {
            swal("Deleted!", "Your imaginary file has been deleted.", "success");
        });*/
    }
});
```

Comment: i tried this, working fine when i click cancel, but when i click delete, it is not working. Check out my new edit that how i tried.

Comment: @karthikshankar Why did you declare option of 'http' inside that? Did that work well before? Try moving `var httpreq={...}` out of 'http' like my modified code.

Comment: Thank you very much @Canet Robern i) I wrongly declared. ii) No, that does not work as i used the variable before declaring. iii) Yes i moved `var httpreq = {...}` out of `$http(httpreq)` and it worked..

Comment: @karthikshankar Good for you it's working. :) Have a nice day.